# using join tables as a parameter for a JPA

Tags: java, orm, jpa-2.0, jpql, join

In the following entity class from database how to write a query to select from the table
using the collection productsCollection2 as a parameter and retreiving productsCollection3.???
Can i use the productCollection2 and pass list to it using the IN clause to select.

```
@Table(name = "Products")
public class Products implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "SKU")
    private String sku;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ProductName")
    private String productName;

    private boolean allowPreOrder;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "productsCollection")
    private Collection<Categories> categoriesCollection;
    @JoinTable(name = "Products_CrossSell", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "SKU", referencedColumnName = "SKU")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "CrossSKU", referencedColumnName = "SKU")})
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<Products> productsCollection;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "productsCollection")
    private Collection<Products> productsCollection1;
    @JoinTable(name = "Products_Related", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "SKU", referencedColumnName = "SKU")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "RelatedSKU", referencedColumnName = "SKU")})
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<Products> productsCollection2;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "productsCollection2")
    private Collection<Products> productsCollection3;
```

Comment: The query which i wrote looks like this :
select productCollection3 from products where productCollection2 in (1,2,3);

Comment: i found a workaround by using joins.is there some other method??